# How to parse lines after a certain text in python

Tags: python, parsing, format, file-handling

I am trying to parse a text file. I need certain line of it only. I need to search for "tool> exit"
and parse all lines after that until 2nd last line. Here is the text I am trying to parse -

```
complete
line:567       finish;
tool> exit
  Finish Failed  Myname
       0      0   ABC_dog_ctl
       5      1   ABC_cator_t
      34      0   ABC_cator_t
       0      0   ABC_cator_t
  Total = 12,  Failing = 4
  summary at 70s
TOOL:   mytool
```

I am trying to parse only -

```
  Finish Failed  Myname
       0      0   ABC_dog_ctl
       5      1   ABC_cator_t
      34      0   ABC_cator_t
       0      0   ABC_cator_t
  Total = 12,  Failing = 4
  summary at 70s
```

I am trying something like -

```
my_list = []
for line_no, line in enumerate(Infile):
    if "tool> exit" in line:
        start_line = line_no
        my_list.append[line+1]
```

But I am not getting desired result. There are multiple instances of "TOOL" so I can't search it, but it's the last line so I think I can look for line above it always.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "But I am not getting desired result." What result *do* you get, and *how is that different* from the desired result?

Comment: `line+1` makes no sense. `line` is a string, you can't add 1 to it.

Comment: Use `readlines()` to make a list of all the lines in the file. Then you can find the index of the line with `tool> exit`, and use a slice to get the lines you want: `all_lines[index+1:-3]`

Comment: The problem with @Barmar's suggestion is that the line with `tool> exit` would have to look exactly like this to work. The way you used `in` to detect that line made me think it might not be the case.

Comment: @Orius You can use a loop with `in` to find it.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, but then you'd loop once to find the index and then, under the hood, loop a second time to slice it, wouldn't you? The code will probably more elegant though.

Comment: @Orius The slice doesn't have to loop over the same entries we looped over to find the marker. So it's essentially just one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
my_list = []
reached_tool_exit = False
for line in Infile:
  if "tool> exit" in line:
    reached_tool_exit = True
  if reached_tool_exit:
    my_list.append(line)
my_list = my_list[:-1]
```

Edit:

Actually, you should use `del my_list[-1]` instead of `my_list = my_list[:-1]`. That's more efficient.